# With option -tui, GDB exits with "TUI mode is not allowed"

Tags: gdb

I am running gdb `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-51.el7` version. My TUI mode was working seamlessly. 
Suddenly, now it is giving error `"TUI mode not allowed"` upon issuing command `layout src`. When I try to run gdb with `-tui` option, gdb is exiting immediately with `"TUI mode not allowed"`.

*Asked as new question because none of other threads could help.

Comment: Have you modified your `~/.inputrc` file ? See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15163.

Comment: Is that the actual text?  I could only find "TUI mode is not supported".  This error occurs when TUI mode is not compiled in to gdb.

Comment: maybe remove gdb-minimal and install gdb to see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506317/how-to-enable-tui-for-gdb-on-debian-9

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. 
To solve it you have to recompile gdb with TUI support.

These are the steps for Ubuntu:

```
apt-get build-dep gdb
apt-get source gdb
cd gdb-7.7.1 
./configure --enable-tui=yes
make
# grab a coffee
sudo make install
```

Now you can use TUI with gdb :D

```
gbd --tui
```

If you still have issues, try to move the new gdb binary to /usr/bin.
the new binary is on the directory gdb.

Comment: I am having a similar issue to the original poster. My GDB has suddenly stopped allowing tui mode. However, when it did work correctly I never had to explicitly start gdb with --tui ??

Answer (score 0):

Im on Debian 12 and could use gdb by default. After running `apt install gdb` it installed a version with tui support.